# on and hover not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jquery code 
It's not working when

```
   $("a").on("hover",function(){$(this).css("background","#ccc");},function(){$(this).css("background","#fff")});
```

But is working when

```
$("a").hover(function(){$(this).css("background","#ccc");},function(){$(this).css("background","#fff")});
```

How to make it to work with hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `.on()` hover it will look like

```
$("a").on('hover', function(e) {
  if(e.type =='mouseenter') {
   // code for mouseenter
  } else {
   // code for mouseleave
  }
});
```

But for `.hover()` is accept two functions first one for `mouseenter` and second one for `mouseleave`.

```
$('a').hover(
  // for mouseenter
  function() {

  },
  // for mouseleave
  function() {

  }
);
```

So if you want to use `.on()` then your code will:

```
$("a").on('hover', function(e) {
  if(e.type =='mouseenter') {
     // code for mouseenter
     $(this).css("background","#ccc");
  } else {
     // code for mouseleave
     $(this).css("background","#fff")
  }
});
```

As **[@ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster)** comment if you want to bind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` separately then you can try:

```
$('a')
     .mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css('background', '#ccc');
      })
     .mouseleave(function() {
         $(this).css('background', '#fff');
      });
```

or using `.on()` you can do

```
$('a').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
     $(this).css('background', '#ccc');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
     $(this).css('background', '#fff');
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd rather bind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` separately. More readable IMO.

Comment: @thecodeparadox, Sir, as doc says `hover` is an shorthand for `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`, so second event in `hover` is for `mouseleave` not `mouseout`. Though I dont know if there is much difference.

Comment: @Joy **The simple difference is that in the case with mouseout there is not event bubbling by default, while in mouseleave the events bubble.**

Answer (score 1):

Hover is an shortcut for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. So you can bind those using on like

```
$("a").on({ 
           mouseenter: function(){$(this).css("background","#ccc");},
           mouseleave: function(){$(this).css("background","#fff");}
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NB7Yb/)

And the code

```
$("a").on('hover', function(e) {
  if(e.type =='mouseenter') {
      // do something when mouse enter
      alert("mouse enter");
  } else {
      // do something when mouse leave
      alert("mouse leave");
  }
});​
```